# Want to know size of copper wire used in 12v relays

Tags: relay

I want to know the specifications of the wire insulating wire used in 12v relay. Specifications include diameter of wire, Gauge, etc.

[image]

Comment: This can't be answered because it depends on the mechanical force the relay needs to build to move the contacts. Greater force needed->more current needed->thicker wire needed.

Comment: Buy one. Pull it apart. Measure. It'll cost less than the time you spend to find out any other way. But it'll only be valid for that model of relay.

Comment: i am asking about perticular relay shown in image

Comment: The image shows a 24V relay.

Comment: Sorry I am asking about diameter not length

Comment: Sorry again, but we can't answer that. Please link a datasheet. One can try to make an informed guess from the coil impedance and the voltage.

Comment: Engineers that are not capable of taking their curiosity into their own hands by ripping apart existing products and performing a detailed investigation are not engineers at all!!

Comment: "wire insulating wire", what is that?

Comment: @DaveTweed: The image I see is of a SONGLE  SRD-12VDC-SL-C, which is a relay with a 12 volt DC coil.

Comment: @EM Fields: The OP originally had put the picture of a similar 24V relay there.

Comment: Why do you care?  What application requires you to know this?

Answer (score 7):

Your question can't be answered except by the manufacturer from looking at the outside of a relay.  You have no way of knowing the pull-in force and magnetic field strength required to activate the relay, so you can't calculate it from that.  There are other variables too.

There is no reason you need to know this to use a relay effectively, and the manufacturer will likely consider it none of your business, and probably proprietary anyway.

If you really want to know for some reason, buy a relay, take it apart, and measure whatever parameters you want to know.